# Source folder is not a Java project when working with Heroku eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, heroku, playframework-2.0

I have set up a new project and hooked it up with Heroku:

[image]

I'm able to make changes and upload them to my dyno at Heroku but when trying to add new classes in eclipse I get **Source folder is not a Java project **.
Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok found it, needed to tell eclipse that this was a java project by adding:

```
<natures>
    <nature>
         <name></name>
     </nature>
     <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
 </natures>
```

So that the .project file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>morning-garden-3028</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
    <nature>
      <name></name>
    </nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
  </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Source->Add Folder`, and add your source folder

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't have that option since my project wasn't set to a java project.