# Source folder is not a java project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am working on eclipse on my mac and using gitHub to import a project. The import works fine except that when I try to add a class it doesn't work an says "Source folder is not a java project" I have googled this error some sources came up but nothing that solves my problem.

Comment: Probably this will help :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663440/source-folder-is-not-a-java-project-when-working-with-heroku-eclipse-plugin

Comment: My project doesn't even have a .project file, where do I add this code?

Comment: Also, it doesn't even have a Java build path when I open Project -> Properties

Answer (score 0):

**edited.**

You can specify it in Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source

It's kind of common practice, that open source project doesn't have any specific project settings for Eclipse or Idea or for some other environment tool. Usually those files are in git ignore or in git exclude.

Comment: That creates an empty project though